# .NET CIL Code Size

Tags: .net, cil, code-size

When looking at the compiled **CIL**, I notice the code size is included in the compiled CIL.  It is commented out.  Below is an example

C#:

```
static void MakeACar()
{
Car myCar = new Car();
}
```

CIL:

```
.method public hidebysig static void MakeAObject() cil managed
{
    //Code size 7 (0x7)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init ([0] class SimpleGC.Car c)
    IL_0000: newobj instance void SimpleGC.Car::.ctor()
    IL_0005: stloc.O
    IL_0006: ret
}
```

What does the code size represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just the number of bytes occupied by the CIL in it's bytecode form.

(Take a look at your example: You can see that the last instruction (`ret`) begins at byte offset 6 (`IL_0006:`). Since [`ret` is encoded as a one-byte opcode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ret.aspx), the bytecode stream ends up having a total length of 6 + 1 = 7 bytes.)

Comment: What do you mean?  Is this the actual size of the generated code, or the size of the newly created Car class that will be put on the managed heap?

Comment: The actual size of the generated (assembled) CIL code. For example, a ret instruction has the bytecode representation `2A`. stloc.0 also occupies 1 byte, and the newobj instruction is 1 byte followed by a 4 byte methoddef.